# Can std::make_unique take the output of a function as an argument?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

Is there a way to use make_unique and pass the output of a function as a parameter?

```
auto loadedSurface1 = std::unique_ptr<SDL_Surface,SurfaceDeleter>(IMG_Load(path.c_str()));
auto loadedSurface2 = std::make_unique<SDL_Surface, SurfaceDeleter>();
loadedSurface2.reset(IMG_Load(path.c_str()));
auto loadedSurface3 = std::make_unique<SDL_Surface, SurfaceDeleter>(IMG_Load(path.c_str())));
```

SurfaceDeleter is a functor.

loadedSurface1 and loadedSurface2 both work fine. loadedSurface3 fails ( no instance of overloaded function matches the argument list)

If there's no way to make loadedSurface3 work, is loadedSurface2 recommended over loadedSurface1 because it uses make_unique?

Comment: What do you mean when you say it "fails"? What happens exactly? Present a [MCVE].

Comment: How does it fail? Elaborate please.

Comment: When you do `std::make_unique<SDL_Surface, SurfaceDeleter>` you are not specifying the type of the deleter of the `unique_ptr`, but specifying that `SurfaceDeleter` is the type of the first argument to `std::make_unique`. You cannot use `std::make_unique` to create a `unique_ptr` with a custom deleter. Compare with the [declaration of `make_unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique).

Comment: Why are you answering in comments :(

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Our understanding of what an answer is differs. Neither my comment nor your answer answer the question.

Comment: `path.c_str` looks extremely suspicious. `std::string::c_str()` is a function. Now other objects theoretically can have a data member with the same name, but the convention definitely is that `c_str` is a function returning a C-style null-terminated string, even on other classes.

Comment: Whoops, you are 100% right. I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to use make_unique and pass the output of a function as a parameter?

`std::make_unique<T>` takes constructor arguments to create a new `T`. It does not take a `T*` to an existing `T`.

Furthermore, [you can't specify a deleter with it like that](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique).

You mean simply:

```
std::unique_ptr<SDL_Surface, SurfaceDeleter> loadedSurface3{IMG_Load(path.c_str())};
```

---

> is loadedSurface2 recommended over loadedSurface1 because it uses make_unique?

I can't see any benefit there. All you've achieved is to split your construction over two lines and lose the deleter.

Comment: @user250095 Correct ;)